# how to split dataframe column value and take only first two strings to new column

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a column in dataframe which has string values like

```
"Hardware part not present"
"Software part not present"
null
null
```

I want to split wrt " " and take only first 2 strings to new column and if it is null then even new column value should be null as well. how to achieve this?

result needed

```
column                               New column
Hardware part not present           Hardware part
Software part not present           Software part
null                                null
null                                null
```

how to achieve this using pyspark or python

Comment: How many columns do you need to rename in your application? If <5 I dont think the added complexity is worth it when you can simply rename with df.rename(columns....)

Comment: You can use the [split](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) method for regular strings and a simple condition for null values

Comment: how to split like fater fist two spaces and take 0th index value

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`substring_index`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.substring_index.html#pyspark.sql.functions.substring_index) function.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

......
df = df.withColumn('New column', F.substring_index('column', ' ', 2))
```

Comment: Great answer! Straight to the point!

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has a built in split method. Here you can define the total number of splits to limit how deep it goes into the string.

```py
df[“existingcol”].str.split(n=2, expand=true)
```

This will give you 3 columns. Then just concat the first 2, and then drop any unnecessary cols.

Doco for reference:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html

It defaults to splitting on white space, but if you think there’ll be a comma or something in there, you can always split on a regex pattern.

Comment: The question is for PySpark, not for Pandas.

Answer (score 0):

In pyspark, you can achieve this using [`concat_ws`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws.html#pyspark-sql-functions-concat-ws), [`slice`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.slice.html#pyspark-sql-functions-slice) and [`split`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.split.html#pyspark-sql-functions-split) functions.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('text_frst2', 
               func.when(func.col('text').isNotNull(), 
                         func.concat_ws(' ', func.slice(func.split('text', ' '), 1, 2))
                         )
               ). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +----------------------------+-------------+
# |text                        |text_frst2   |
# +----------------------------+-------------+
# |software part is not present|software part|
# |hardware part is not present|hardware part|
# |null                        |null         |
# |foo bar baz                 |foo bar      |
# +----------------------------+-------------+
```

- `split` will split the text based on the provided delimiter (in this case `" "`)
- `slice` will retain N number of elements starting from K<sup>th</sup> position (in this case `N=2` and `K=1`)
- `concat_ws` concatenates the array elements delimited by the provided delimiter (in this case `" "`)
- I used a `when()` to only use the operations on non-null values as this generates a space/blank value for null

Comment: Hi Samkart, i was using similar command :        new_df=Flag_df.withColumn('error_part', func.when(func.col('CertificationVariant_errors').isNotNull(), func.concat_ws(' ', func.slice(func.split('CertificationVariant_errors', ' '), 1,2))))

Comment: its saying "NameError: name 'func' is not defined"

Comment: got it imported function as func and its working.. thnaks for your help

Comment: @HarshithKR - yes, i added that as well